# import the dataset in Python with sci-kit learn for machine learning problems_dataset Winscosin breast cancer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, spyder, sklearn-pandas

Hello I try to import a dataset to spyder

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data1.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,0:9].values
y= dataset.iloc[:,9].values
```

but when i display the X matrix in the variable explorer it says that object arrays are currently not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
X = dataset.drop('column_9', 1).values
y = dataset['column_9'].values
```

Just replace `column_9` with whatever the target column's name is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Spyder we can't see the object array. We can only see the data-frame data, but the Spyder team promised that they will provide the object array feature in Spyder 4 (to be released later in 2019).

Answer (score 0):

You can even load data from sklearn module this way:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
X = cancer.data
y = cancer.target
```